# How do I fetch specific build of code from SVN using CruiseControl?

Tags: .net, svn

I am using cruise control .net for fetching code from SVN for an application. I want to fetch it on the basis of changed sets, below is the scenario.

If one team is working on build 1 and second team is working on build 2 and they are committing their code on SVN regularly.

I want to fetch code only of build 1, not of build 2. How can I get it using cruise controls .net? an example will be much appreciated

Comment: Are Team1 and Team2 are committing to separate branches?

Comment: No they are committing code in same branch.

Comment: Then how is it you're supposed to tell CruiseControl, or ANYONE really, that you have two distinct builds?

Comment: Can you please tell me that SVN supports feature of changesets or anything else that can help here what is a simple way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each commit to SVN has a unique revision number. For example, to update the working version to a particular revision, use:

```
svn update -r REV
```

Where `REV` is the revision number of build 1 or build 2. See SVNBook for more information on [`svn update`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html).

Alternatively, if the teams have branched their builds, use [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html). For example:

```
svn switch URL
```

where `URL` is the URL to the branch. If you do not know the revision number used for a build, use [svn log](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) to see a history of changes and which revision was the HEAD when a build was done.

> Can you please tell me if change-set is a feature of Source Control?

"Change set" can mean different things for different source control systems. I assume you are asking whether the source control system (1) uniquely identifies a set of files that makes a change and (2) whether the change is atomic. Yes, SVN does both. Each commit (change) is uniquely identified by a revision number.

> How can we achieve it using cruise control and nant?

Look at the NantContrib [svn](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/svn.html), [svn-checkout](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/svn-checkout.html) and [svn-update](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/svn-update.html) Nant tasks. For example, to get the code for myproject into c:\src where c:\src is not a working set, use:

```
        <svn-checkout 
             destination="c:\src" 
             svnroot="http://server/svn/repos/projects/myproject" 
             revision="HEAD"
             username="user"
             password="password" 
              />
```

and replace HEAD with the desired revision number.

Comment: How can we achieve it using cruise control and nant? Can you please tell me if change-set is a feature of Source Control? What is a simple way to get this working?

Comment: @Rup I have expanded my question to answer the above questions.

Comment: I am using this to fetch code on basis of revision number and it is working. Here is the code of my ccnet.config...
Where I am entering revision number 
<tasks> <nant> <executable>D:\nant-0.92-bin\nant-0.92\bin\nant.exe</executable>
 <buildFile>D:\NANT_SCRIPTS\build.xml</buildFile> <buildTimeoutSeconds>120</buildTimeoutSeconds>
 <buildArgs>-D:Rev=$[Revision]</buildArgs> </nant> </tasks>
and below is the code for fetching code from nant on basis of revision number 
<exec commandline="checkout testproject.repositoryhosting.com/svn/test/Mockups/Test@${Rev} D:\MyTest--username test--password dp"/>

Comment: Based on the above. Is there any way for me to get only code from build1 not from build2?

Comment: @Rup If they are committing to the same branch, you cannot. If both teams are committing to the same branch, they are mixing their code changes. The correct way to do this is to use separate branches. You can separate them by branching from build1 and reapplying the commits from each team to each branch.